# linechart itemtap is not firing in sencha touch 2.3

Tags: sencha-touch

Itemtap is not firing in SenchaTouch 2.3 - I need to tap on item in a Linechart . Now tried as like

> ```
>    this.down('').on('itemtap', function(){}
> ```
>
> in initialize .
>  
>   First time it is working fine.But when again take the screen it's not working.